# how to remove syntax with uniq characters from line

Tags: linux, shell-script, text-processing, sed, perl

we have the following configuration file, `env.gc.txt`

```
export SERVER_GC_OPTS="-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:{{hbase_log_dir}}/gc.log-`date +'%Y%m%d%H%M'`"
```

We try to remove the `` -`date +'%Y%m%d%H%M'` `` syntax from the line containing `SERVER_GC_OPTS`

```
sed -i '/SERVER_GC_OPTS/ s/-`date +'%Y%m%d%H%M'`//g'
```

or

```
sed '/SERVER_GC_OPTS/ s/-\`date +'%Y%m%d%H%M'\`//g'
```

but without success.

What is the best right approach to remove the syntax - `` -`date +'%Y%m%d%H%M'` `` from the line ?

(Note: a `perl` one liner is also an option)

Expected output in `env.gc.txt`

```
export SERVER_GC_OPTS="-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:{{hbase_log_dir}}/gc.log"
```

Comment: you just change `'` with `"` and use `\\` : sed "/SERVER_GC_OPTS/s/-\`date +'%Y%m%d%H%M'\`//"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or, just look for a backtick, some non-backtick chars, and another backtick to remove *any* command substitutions in the file:

```
sed -i '/SERVER_GC_OPTS/ s/-`[^`]\+`//g' file
```

The equivalent perl would be

```
perl -i -pe '/SERVER_GC_OPTS/ && s/-\`.+?\`//g' file
```

Answer (score 4):

The single quote used in the `date` command is breaking the `sed` script.

Try this:

```
sed '/SERVER_GC_OPTS/s/-`date \+.*"$/"/' env.gc.txt
```

This will remove the string `` -`date + `` and everything until the ending double quote.

Comment: Would be good to use modern syntax `$( ... )` instead of backticks

Answer (score 0):

One way out is to use double quotes around `sed`, like as:

```
sed   "/SERVER_GC_OPTS/ s/-\`date +'%Y%m%d%H%M'\`//g"
```

We backslash the backticks since they come alive under double quotes.